# Exploiting XSS in JQuery 1.7.2 Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, web-applications

I am testing a web application that is sporting JQuery version 1.7.2, which I found out is vulnerable to DOM-based XSS with class Attribute ('.XSS_VECTOR') Reference: http://domstorm.skepticfx.com/modules?id=529bbe6e125fac0000000003

How do I actually exploit this vulnerability for a POC? can anyone point in the right direction?

Comment: But, in the same link that you provided, they write a sample code...the `function test`, where they inject an exploit inside an iframe....

Comment: I saw the sample code, but didn't know how to utilize it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from a call like this:

```
$('. <img src=x onerror=bad();>')
```

jQuery will try to create the `<img>` element, and but it will get an error trying to load it from the nonexistent `x` URL, and then the `bad()` function will be called.

This is a jQuery bug because a selector beginning with `.` is supposed to just try to find an element in the DOM, it shouldn't create new elements. It's acting as if you'd written:

```
$('<img src=x onerror=bad();>')
```

which is the syntax for creating an element.